# Populate max value to adjacent record for the same key using Pig

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I have data set below

```
key,value
---------
key1|10
key1|20
key1|30
key2|50
key2|70
```

I need to populate new column for the same key with max "value" column.

Output must be

```
key1|10|30
key1|20|30
key1|30|30
key2|50|70
key2|70|70

Below is the Pig script, but facing issues.
A = LOAD 'input.txt' using PigStorage('|');
B = foreach A generate $0,$1,min($1); 


grunt> A = LOAD 'input.txt' using PigStorage('|');
grunt> B = foreach A generate $0,$1,max($1);

2017-05-26 06:48:02,347 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1070: Could not resolve max using imports: [, java.lang., org.apache.pig.builtin., org.apache.pig.impl.builtin.]
```

Comment: Your question says `max`, you're using `min`. BTW, it's `MIN`. Also, you're using pipes to split a comma delimited file.

Comment: typo mistake, updated the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code should do. Remember that you need to `group` the relation first before you can use functions like `MAX`, `MIN`, `AVG`.

```
A = load 'file' using PigStorage(',') as (id: chararray, val: int);
B = GROUP A by id;
C = FOREACH B GENERATE FLATTEN(group), MAX(A.val) as (maxval: int);
D = JOIN A by id, C BY group;
E = FOREACH D generate A::id, A::val, C::maxval;
DUMP E;
```

Run this and you should get:

```
(key1,30,30)
(key1,20,30)
(key1,10,30)
(key2,70,70)
(key2,50,70)
```

Comment: Working like a charm

Comment: If I add 2 more columns to the dataset like fname,lname........
B= GROUP A by(id,fname,lname)
C = FOREACH B GENERATE FLATTEN(group), MAX(A.val) as (maxval: int);
D = JOIN A by (id,fname,lname), C BY GROUP;
getting error, pig script failed to parse.

Comment: Since the group in relation C has the same columns, you can try  `D = JOIN A by (id,fname,lname), C by (id,fname,lname);`

Comment: @useriw tip : use `illustrate` command to check the schema of a relation and proceed accordingly.

Comment: sure.. Thanks for the input.